# '(key: String, value: Any)' is not convertible to '[String : Any]'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to refactor this code:

```
var indices = [String:[Int:Double]]()
apps.forEach { app in indices[app] = [Int:Double]()}
    
var index = 0
timeSeries.forEach { entry in
    entry.apps.forEach{ (arg: (key: String, value: Double)) in
        let (app, value) = arg
        indices[app]?[index] = value
    }
        
    index += 1
}
```

so I have the signature:

```
var parameters = timeSeries.map{ entry in entry.apps as [String:Any] }
var indices = getIndices(with: apps, in: parameters) as? [String:[Int:Double]] ?? [String:[Int:Double]]()
```

and the method:

```
func getIndices(with source: [String], in entryParameters: [[String:Any]]) -> [String:[Int:Any]] {
    var indices = [String:[Int:Any]]()
    source.forEach { item in indices[item] = [Int:Any]() }
    
    var index = 0
    entryParameters.forEach { (arg: (key: String, value: Any)) in
        let (key, value) = arg
        indices[key]?[index] = value
        
        index += 1
    }

    return indices
}
```

But this (only in the method, not the original, which works fine) gives: `'(key: String, value: Any)' is not convertible to '[String : Any]'` at the *entryParameters* line

The reason I must use `Any` is because the other source is [String:[Int:Bool]]

## edit: some more details:

timeSeries is `[TimeSeriesEntry]`

```
// this will need to be defined per-model, so in a different file in final project
struct TimeSeriesEntry: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let date: Date
    let apps: [String:Double]
    let locations: [String:Bool]
    
    func changeApp(app: String, value: Double) -> TimeSeriesEntry {
        var apps = self.apps
        apps[app] = value
        
        return TimeSeriesEntry(id: self.id, uid: self.uid, date: self.date, apps: apps, locations: self.locations)
    }
}
```

### notes:

changed calling signature, thanks impression. problem remains.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[String:Any]` not `[[String:Any]]`?

Comment: if I do that than my calling line (assigning to indicies) gives `Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Double]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'` at `timeSeries.map`-- I added detail of the structure of timeSeries for clarity

Comment: Well that's because you are doing `timeSeries.map{ entry in entry.apps }) as? [String:[Int:Double]] ?? [String:[Int:Double]]()` So, I guess it depends what you want. In both cases it seems you type cast to `[String:[Int:Double]]` or `[String:[Int:Double]]()` Now, you say you need it for `bool` as well. However, if that is the case, then when you take it into the parameter, you'd need to turn your `[String:[Int:Double]]` into `[String:Any]` when it comes into the function as a parameter

Comment: I'd recommend trying `timeSeries.map{ entry in entry.apps }) as? [String:Any] ?? [String:[Int:Double]]()` because if `[String:Any]` returns nil, then you know you need a new one, i.e. `[String:[Int:Double]]`

Comment: no the outer cast is on the return value, not on the parameter. look closely, the parameter is an array of TimeSeriesEntry.app `[String:Double]`. The cast is `[String:[Int:Double]]`, again, on the return value (the left side type specification in the assignment doesnt need to be there I suppose, but the right does). `[String:Double]`should gracefully downcast to ´[String:Any]´ without m,e coercing it, shouldn't it?

Comment: just to make sure, I changed calling signature, thanks impression. but problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every value in `entryParameters` is a dictionary so when you do `entryParameters.forEach` you get dictionary type in the closure not `(key, value)`.

You will get `(key,value)` when you call the `forEach` on this dictionary. So your method should look something like this:

```
func getIndices(with source: [String], in entryParameters: [[String:Any]]) -> [String:[Int:Any]] {
    var indices = [String:[Int:Any]]()
    source.forEach { item in indices[item] = [Int:Any]() }

    var index = 0
    entryParameters.forEach { entry in
        entry.forEach {(arg: (key: String, value: Any)) in
            let (key, value) = arg
            indices[key]?[index] = value
        }

        index += 1
    }

    return indices
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this briefly in Playground.

```
var double = [String:[Int:Double]]()
double["Taco"] = [2: 3.2]

func myFunc(double: [String:[Int:Double]]) {
    print(double.count) //Prints 1
    print(double["Taco"]!) //Prints [2:3.2]
}

func myFunc2(all: [String:Any]) {
    print(all.count) //Prints 1
    print(all["Taco"]!) //Prints [2:3.2]
}


myFunc(double: double)
myFunc2(all: double as [String:Any])
```

I have my initial `[String:[Int:Double]]()`. Inside this dictionary I set `double["Taco"] = [2: 3.2]`. I can use 2 different functions, one that is taken as the original type `[String:[Int:Double]]` and it is easy to use as the functions take in the same parameter type. However, now I created a function that takes in a dictionary of `[String:Any]`. Now, to USE this method, we MUST typecast variables as `[String:Any]` when calling the method, as you can see below.